# If condition using json to scrape multiple links

Tags: r, json, web-scraping, rvest

I am using `json` to scrape the content of multiple (1000) links. However, some of the links do not work in json format so there is not content to be scraped. Due to this, my code stop working when finding one of those links.

I have tried to use `TryCatch` to avoid the error but it seems not to be working

## Here is the code I am using

```
library(jsonlite)
library(rvest)

lapply(links_jason[1:6], function(x) {
  tryCatch(
    {
  json_data <- read_html(x) %>% html_text()%>%
    jsonlite::fromJSON(.)%>%
    select(1)
    },
  error = function(cond) return(NULL),
  finally = print(x)
  )
})
```

## This is the issue I am getting

`Debug location is approximate beacuse the source is not available`

## Here are some examples of the links I am trying to scrape

Links number 1, 2 and 6 works fine. 3, 4 and 5 needs to be avoid

```
> head(links_jason)
[1] "https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/68077&_format=hal_json"
[2] "https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/57833&_format=hal_json"
[3] "https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/56774&_format=hal_json"
[4] "https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/56748&_format=hal_json"
[5] "https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/56782&_format=hal_json"
[6] "https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/64341&_format=hal_json"
```

I have also tried to use if statements with no results. Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you tell which packages you use please?

Comment: Hi, @Chelmy88 `jsonlite`, `rvest`,

Comment: If I check the third link you provide (https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/56774&_format=hal_json), there is nothing on that page. So apparently it is not an R issue. Can you please check the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read direct with jsonlite and test length of return

```
library(jsonlite)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

links_jason <- c("https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/68077&_format=hal_json"
,"https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/57833&_format=hal_json"
, "https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/56774&_format=hal_json"
, "https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/56748&_format=hal_json"
, "https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/56782&_format=hal_json"
,"https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/64341&_format=hal_json")


lapply(links_jason[1:6], function(x) {

      json_data <- jsonlite::read_json(x)
      if(length(json_data)>0){
        print(x)
      }
}
```

---

Or something like:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

links_jason <- c("https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/68077&_format=hal_json"
,"https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/57833&_format=hal_json"
, "https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/56774&_format=hal_json"
, "https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/56748&_format=hal_json"
, "https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/56782&_format=hal_json"
,"https://lasillavacia.com/silla_llena_api/get?path=/contenido-nodo/64341&_format=hal_json")


lapply(links_jason[1:6], function(x) {
      json_data <- jsonlite::read_json(x)
      if(length(json_data)==0){
        json_data <- NA}
      else{
          print('doing something with json_data')
        }
      })
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the `if` including this part of the code `json_data <- read_html(x) %>% html_text()%>%` I tried to use `lapply(links_jason[1:6], function(x) {
  json_data <- read_html(x) %>% html_text()%>%
    if(length(json_data)>0)
  json_data <- NA` but I get `argument is not interpretable as logical`

Comment: See edt for one way around that

Comment: This is what I get with the second option `> json_data
[1] NA` I am not getting the content of each link with neither of the options you have suggested. Why is that?

Comment: Because I haven't written anything to extract content. I simply either leave as json_data if url is good - then you can extract whatever it is you want, or I assign N/A to  json_data if url is bad. You could add an else and then do your extraction there.

Comment: Thanks! I assigned NA and then I did the scrape of the content.